# Solve system of trigonometric equations

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

How would you solve a system like this

$$ \left\{
 \begin{aligned}
  0&=E-\sin\left(\theta_1\right) + K \sin\left(\theta_2 - \theta_1\right)\\
  0&=E+\sin\left(\theta_2\right) - K \sin\left(\theta_2- \theta_1\right)
 \end{aligned}
\right.
$$

for $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$?

I tried

Adding the two equations gives
$$
\begin{aligned}
 0=2E-\sin\left(\theta_1\right)+\sin\left(\theta_2\right)&\iff \sin\left(\theta_1\right) = 2E+\sin\left(\theta_2\right) \\
 &\iff\sin\left(\theta_2\right)=-2E + \sin\left(\theta_1\right)
 \end{aligned}
$$
Subtracting the first equation from the second gives
$$
\begin{aligned}
 0&=\sin\left(\theta_1\right) + \sin\left(\theta_2\right) -2K\sin\left(\theta_2- \theta_1\right)\\
 &=\sin\left(\theta_1\right)+\sin\left(\theta_2\right)-2K\left(\sin\left(\theta_2\right)\cos\left(\theta_1\right)-\sin\left(\theta_1\right)\cos\left(\theta_2\right)\right)\\
 &=\sin\left(\theta_1\right)\left(1+2K\cos\left(\theta_2\right)\right) + \sin\left(\theta_2\right)\left(1-2K\cos\left(\theta_1\right)\right)\\
 \end{aligned}
$$
From above,
$$
\begin{aligned}
 0&=\left(2E+\sin\left(\theta_2\right)\right)\left(1+2K\cos\left(\theta_2\right)\right) + \left(-2E + \sin\left(\theta_1\right)\right)\left(1-2K\cos\left(\theta_1\right)\right)\\
 \iff
 0&=2E+2EK\cos\left(\theta_2\right)+\sin\left(\theta_2\right)+K\sin\left(2\theta_2\right)\\
 &-2E+2EK\cos\left(\theta_1\right)+\sin\left(\theta_1\right)-K\sin\left(2\theta_1\right)
 \end{aligned}
$$
Moving all $\theta_2$ terms to the left hand side gives
$$
\begin{aligned}
-2EK\cos\left(\theta_2\right)-\sin\left(\theta_2\right)-K\sin\left(2\theta_2\right)&=2EK\cos\left(\theta_1\right)+\sin\left(\theta_1\right)-K\sin\left(2\theta_1\right)
 \\
 \iff
 2EK\cos\left(\pi-\theta_2\right)+\sin\left(-\theta_2\right)-K\sin\left(2\theta_2\right)&=2EK\cos\left(\theta_1\right)+\sin\left(\theta_1\right)-K\sin\left(2\theta_1\right)\\
 \end{aligned}
$$

But this doesn't seem to take me anywhere.

From problem formulation "I found that this problem is
most easily done analytically and 'by hand'".

Comment: Use $\cos x = \pm\sqrt{1 - \sin^2 x}$ to get rid of the cosines.

Comment: How wold that help? If it helps, this will introduce certainly introduce false roots

Answer (score 1):

May be, we could define $\theta_3=\theta_2-\theta_1$ and rewrite the equations as $$\left\{
 \begin{aligned}
  0&=E-\sin\left(\theta_1\right) + K \sin\left(\theta_3\right)\\
  0&=E+\sin\left(\theta_2\right) - K \sin\left(\theta_3\right)
 \end{aligned}
\right.$$

So, we can solve for $\theta_1$ and  $\theta_2$ as functions of  $\theta_3,E,K$  $$\theta_1=\sin^{-1}\big(K\sin(\theta_3)+E\big)$$ $$\theta_2=\sin^{-1}\big(K\sin(\theta_3)-E\big)$$ which then gives $$\theta_3=\sin^{-1}\Big(K\sin(\theta_3)-E\Big)-\sin^{-1}\Big(K\sin(\theta_3)+E\Big)$$ $$\sin(\theta_3)=\sin\Big(\sin^{-1}\big(K\sin(\theta_3)-E\big)-\sin^{-1}\big(K\sin(\theta_3)+E\big)\Big)$$Now, setting $x=\sin(\theta_3)$ and expending, we can end with the equation $$x=(Kx-E) \sqrt{1-(E+K x)^2}-(K x+E)\sqrt{1-(E-K x)^2}
  $$ which is not the most pleasant but which could be solved using some numerical methods (the problem is so reduced to a single algebraic equation for a single unknwon).

**Edit**

In fact, this equation has potentially four roots which are given by $$x_{1,2}=\pm \frac{\sqrt{\frac{ \left(8 E^2+4\right) K^2-\sqrt{-\left(4 K^2+1\right)^2
   \left(16 E^2 K^2-1\right)}+1}{K^4}}}{2 \sqrt{2}}$$ $$x_{3,4}=\pm \frac{\sqrt{\frac{\left(8 E^2+4\right) K^2+\sqrt{-\left(4 K^2-1\right)^2 \left(16
   E^2 K^2-1\right)}-1}{K^4}}}{2 \sqrt{2}}$$ but some of them have been introduced by the successive squaring processes.

Answer (score 0):

*Remarks*: Assume that $K \ne 0$. The system of equations has a solution if and only if at least one of the following conditions holds:
(1) $|E| \le 1$;

(2) $|4EK|\le 1$ and
$\left|\sin \frac{\arcsin(-4EK)}{2}\right| \le |2K|$;

(3) $|4EK|\le 1$ and $\left|\cos \frac{\arcsin(-4EK)}{2}\right| \le |2K|$.

$\phantom{2}$

Assume that $K \ne 0$.

Let
$$x = \frac{\theta_2 + \theta_1}{2}, \quad y = \frac{\theta_2 - \theta_1}{2}.$$
Then $\theta_1 = x - y, \theta_2 = x + y$.
The system of equations is written as
\begin{align*}
 E - \sin(x - y) + K \sin 2y &= 0, \tag{1} \\
 E + \sin(x + y) - K\sin 2y &= 0. \tag{2}
\end{align*}

The system (1)-(2) is equivalent to
\begin{align*}
 2\cos y \, (2K \sin y - \sin x) &= 0, \tag{3}\\
 2E + 2\cos x\, \sin y &= 0. \tag{4}
\end{align*}
(*Note*: $(1) - (2) = (3)$, and $(1) + (2) = (4)$. )

From (3), we split into two cases.

**Case 1.** $\cos y = 0$

All the real solutions of the system (3)-(4) are given by
$$y = \frac{\pi}{2} + 2k\pi, \quad k \in \mathbb{Z}, \quad x = 2n\pi \pm \arccos(-E), \quad n \in \mathbb{Z}, $$
and
$$y = \frac{\pi}{2} + (2k+1)\pi, \quad k\in \mathbb{Z}, \quad x = 2n\pi \pm \arccos E, \quad n\in \mathbb{Z}.$$

**Case 2.** $2K\sin y - \sin x = 0$

We have $\sin y = \frac{\sin x}{2K}$.
Plugging $\sin y = \frac{\sin x}{2K}$ into (4), we have $\sin 2x = -4EK$.

All the real solutions of $\sin 2x = -4EK$ are given by
$$x = n\pi + \frac12\arcsin(-4EK), \quad n \in \mathbb{Z}$$
and
$$x = n\pi + \frac12\pi - \frac12\arcsin(-4EK), \quad n\in \mathbb{Z}.$$
Then we can find $y$ via $\sin y = \frac{\sin x}{2K}$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved this problem.

1. Substitution of angles into median $\theta_m = \tfrac{1}{2} ( \theta_1 + \theta_2 )$ and amplitude $\theta_d = \tfrac{1}{2} ( \theta_2 - \theta_1 )$

   $$\begin{aligned} \theta_1 & \rightarrow \theta_m - \theta_d \\ \theta_2 & \rightarrow \theta_m + \theta_d \end{aligned}$$
2. Add the two equations and expand the trig terms to get $$2 \sin (\theta_d) \cos (\theta_m) + 2 E = 0$$
3. Subtract the two equations and expand the trig terms to get $$ \cos(\theta_d) (4 K \sin(\theta_d)-2 \sin(\theta_m)) =0$$
4. Bring the known $K$ and $E$ terms to one side $$ \begin{aligned} E & = -\sin \theta_d \cos \theta_m \\ K & = \frac{ \sin\theta_m }{2 \sin \theta_d} \end{aligned}$$
5. Multiply both equations to get $$E K = -\tfrac{1}{2} \sin \theta_m \cos \theta_m = -\tfrac{1}{4} \sin(2 \theta_m)$$ and solve for $\theta_m$ $$\theta_m = -\tfrac{1}{2} \sin^{-1}\left(4 E K\right) $$ plus $\pi$ multiples, which you might wish to ignore.
6. Use $E = -\sin \theta_d \cos \theta_m$ to solve for $\theta_d$ given $\theta_m$ above $$ \theta_d = \sin^{-1} \left( \frac{ \sqrt{1-4 E K}-\sqrt{1 + 4 E K}}{4 K} \right) - \pi $$ or $$ \theta_d =- \sin^{-1} \left( \frac{ \sqrt{1-4 E K}-\sqrt{1 + 4 E K}}{4 K} \right)  $$
7. Combine $\theta_d$ and $\theta_m$ to solve for $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ $$ \begin{aligned} 
    \theta_1 & = \pi - \tfrac{1}{2} \sin^{-1} ( 4 E K) - \sin^{-1} \left( \frac{ \sqrt{1-4 E K}-\sqrt{1 + 4 E K}}{4 K} \right) \\ 
    \theta_2 & = -\pi - \tfrac{1}{2} \sin^{-1} ( 4 E K) + \sin^{-1} \left( \frac{ \sqrt{1-4 E K}-\sqrt{1 + 4 E K}}{4 K} \right) \end{aligned}$$